# Issues in implementing server side authorization to google drive

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-drive-api

We want to let our GAE for java app to read docs from google drive for the app specific requirements.

For the same I was trying to refer https://developers.google.com/drive/auth/web-server

However, I am unable to understand the code flow. There is no mention like from where to obtain the authorizationCode as mentioned in the code below:

```
 public static Credential getCredentials(String authorizationCode, String state)
      throws CodeExchangeException, NoRefreshTokenException, IOException {
    String emailAddress = "";
    try {
      Credential credentials = exchangeCode(authorizationCode);
      Userinfo userInfo = getUserInfo(credentials);
      String userId = userInfo.getId();
      emailAddress = userInfo.getEmail();
      if (credentials.getRefreshToken() != null) {
        storeCredentials(userId, credentials);
        return credentials;
      } else {
        credentials = getStoredCredentials(userId);
        if (credentials != null && credentials.getRefreshToken() != null) {
          return credentials;
        }
      }
    } catch (CodeExchangeException e) {
```

Any working example of integration between gae for java and google drive?

Answer (score 1):

if you try to have offline access, first of all you must get authorization code which may be redeemed for an access token and a refresh token.

1) Enable Google Drive Services from [Google APIs console](https://code.google.com/apis/console/b/0/?pli=1)

2) Create Client ID for [web applications](https://code.google.com/apis/console/b/0/?pli=1)

then , get authorization code, for instance:

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?access_type=offline
&approval_prompt=auto
&client_id=[your id]
&redirect_uri=[url]
&response_type=code
&scope=[access scopes]
&state=/profile
```

after that, you can call exchangeCode() , and its parameter will be your authorization code that was retrieved before.

Comment: I tried that and having issues in getting refreshToken. Please advise on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17333726/refreshtoken-is-null