# refreshToken is null

Tags: google-app-engine, google-drive-api

I used DREdit app's Oauth code to get accessToken and refreshToken for my app and i am getting the accessToken but refreshToken is coming null always.

I tried to print the values in the code which comes like below

```
authorization URL:https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?access_type=offline&approval_prompt=force&client_id=651991573332.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=http://www.sakshum.org/GoogleOauth&response_type=code&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file%20https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email%20https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile
```

This code already has access_type=offline which I found not having in the url was the cause in some cases. Please advise what else could be wrong here.

The log prints as follows on appEngine

```
[s~sakshumweb-hrd/3.368699522239285323].<stdout>: Code:4/XQ1sR1Pu5VHDqGbG9iJO10bXVCCE.Qn-L1XwrBVYaEnp6UAPFm0EmSoCXfwI

W 2013-07-10 20:20:16.294
com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClient <init>: Application name is not set. Call Builder#setApplicationName.
I 2013-07-10 20:20:16.536
[s~sakshumweb-hrd/3.368699522239285323].<stdout>: id:113470899999229420779

I 2013-07-10 20:20:17.936
[s~sakshumweb-hrd/3.368699522239285323].<stdout>: access token:ya29.AHES6ZSP7MXaaUhMz4RO7Jm3Zkh_s1zUxJyzW_6IvfADaQ

I 2013-07-10 20:20:17.936
[s~sakshumweb-hrd/3.368699522239285323].<stdout>: refresh token:null
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After your link you get authorization code. For instance:

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?access_type=offline
&approval_prompt=auto
&client_id=[your id]
&redirect_uri=[url]
&response_type=code
&scope=[access scopes]
&state=/profile
```

then if in future you are going to have access to drive you need refresh token (you can every time request auth token -  redirecting to google and etc... but it's not good way. after first usage, you should save Credentials in Database with User UID (for instance, it may be mail). So if you need to have access to the drive in the feature you do this:

```
static Credential exchangeCode(String authorizationCode)
      throws CodeExchangeException {
    try {
      GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = getFlow();
      GoogleTokenResponse response =
          flow.newTokenRequest(authorizationCode).setRedirectUri(REDIRECT_URI).execute();
      return flow.createAndStoreCredential(response, null);
    } catch (IOException e) {
      System.err.println("An error occurred: " + e);
      throw new CodeExchangeException(null);
    }
  }
```

As I guess you also want to get url of the file  which is in the  Google Drive. when you get files - [thee the documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/search-parameters), then you will find download methids in com.google.api.services.drive.model.File object.  read  [documentations](http://javadoc.google-api-java-client.googlecode.com/hg-history/2fe3287eff6e00294deaa1deffd32a7fa8884c37/apis/drive/v1/com/google/api/services/drive/model/class-use/File.html)

Answer (score 2):

Refresh tokens are only issued on the initial authorization (whenever the consent screen is shown.) If you find you're in a state where you don't have a saved refresh token for a user, you can ask for reauthorization with the added query parameter prompt=consent. The user will be asked to re-authorize and a new refresh token will be generated.

Comment: Hi yes i got it at the initial authorization which i did manually. But in future the gae app itself need to handle the authorization. So if user is not explicitly revoking the access then what are the reasons that the stored refreshToken will be stale ?

Comment: So long as you correctly save it when it is issued, you should be fine. Issues are mostly limited to edge cases like bugs/errors when persisting the refresh token.

Comment: @SteveBazyl it is possible to get public url of google drive files. so that i can use url for streaming.. could u reply please

Comment: I already write my answer about this :-) yes you can, with google drive API.